# How do I change the way an inspection works in IntelliJ IDEA?(Scala plugin)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

Picture says it all:

[image]

I want the squiggle to be under `Int`, rather than having it under an unintended type (`Unit` in the example)

How do I achieve this behavior?

Comment: This is warning you that your types don't match and your code won't compile, so the best idea is to fix the code so that the warning goes away.

Comment: I agree that a warning is a good thing. However, I would much prefer to have the squiggle under `Int`, rather than having it below a completely new type. That's the default behavior for other languages as well

Comment: I  disagree that "That's the default behavior for other languages." I just tried in Java with `int wha() { return ""; }`, and jshell highlights `""`, not `int`. Haskell and [Pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype) gave similar behavior.

Comment: @Brian I meant that's the default behavior of *Intellij* for other languages

Comment: @nz_21I update my answer, and this is a complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function that returns Int but your implementation returns Unity, you can fix it by providing a default return value or null

```
def wha():Int = {
   0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All kinds of errors, warnings, problems, etc. for certain behavior are pre-setup and called *inspections* in IntelliJ. They are configured in *"Inspections"*(Preferences | Editor | Inspections) for all languages and frameworks separately. The only configuration available there is to enable/disable an inspection and change its severity level - you cannot change **how** they work.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, recently Jetbrains introduced the feature to create custom inspections through [*Structural Search Inspection*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html#). You should be able to create custom inspection for Scala otherwise it's still not achievable.
And there is still no posibility to edit pre-existing inspections though as of version 2020.1